# As a moderator, what action should I take if a user behaves poorly on two sites in separate instances?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

This is, for the moment, purely hypothetical.

Say I am a moderator on sites A and B. On site A, a user behaves somewhat rudely - not enough to warrant a suspension or anything, but still clearly breaking the "Be Nice" policy. The matter is eventually cleared up. Later, on site B, the same user behaves rudely once more in an unrelated incident - again, not rudely enough to warrant a suspension, but still behaving inappropriately.

Let's imagine - for the sake of argument - that there is enough to warrant a suspension *if the actions had been committed on the same site*, because it was a repeated offense that could not be let go. However, the actions were committed on multiple sites.

The actions, however are limited to these two sites.

What should I do? Suspend the user on both sites? Neither site? Is there another option?

Comment: In this hypothetical exercise, are you a moderator on both sites involved or just one?

Comment: @AnnaLear I am a moderator on both sites.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably best answered by a CM, but I'll tender an answer in the mean time.

This all comes down to context and scope.

Keeping in mind that we don't want users being a nuisance, and we especially don't want them breaking the Be Nice® policy, I would suggest you treat the two instances separately, do not combine them - unless together they warrant a request for a network ban. Pinging someone across multiple sites for minor incidents on each *because you aggregated them* could be viewed by some as harassment.

Each site is run as a separate community. While the same basic laws apply everywhere, there is a little bit of discretion as to how each site applies standards, each site has their characters and eccentrics.  As a moderator of a site you are responsible to that community and the fellow moderators for your decisions and actions. It becomes hard to justify your actions *to a specific community* when you ban someone because they were a little bit of a nuisance on one site and a little bit on another site. If a user incurs a suspension on one site that might have some bearing on an independent decision made on the other site, but you shouldn't let the first offense be the major reason for a ban after the second offense.

I would suggest you distance yourself and let another mod handle the second incident. You *could* deal with the second one if you had a successful outcome on the first, but you run the risk of the user perceiving it as harassment and getting hostile and escalating, in which case it can turn unnecessarily sticky and nasty.

In any case keep your fellow mods in the loop, they need to know what's going on.